# How do I correctly use Json Reader to navigate in my Json using retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, json

Here is my API

```
http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all
```

I'm confused on how to use the Json reader methods. I tried looking on its Javadoc, it seems the straightforward but when I implement it, it has different behavior.

Here is my code

```
RestResponse result = null;
        String countryName = null;
        String alpha2Code = null;
        String alpha3Code = null;

    jsonReader.beginObject();
    jsonReader.beginArray();

    while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
        countryName = jsonReader.nextString();
        alpha2Code = jsonReader.nextString();
        alpha3Code = jsonReader.nextString();
    }
    jsonReader.endArray();
    jsonReader.beginArray();

    while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
        jsonReader.beginObject();
        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
            jsonReader.skipValue();
            jsonReader.peek();
        }
        jsonReader.endObject();
    }

    jsonReader.endArray();
```

This is my code for learning how does it navigates my json. This code runs on the read method of TypeAdapter.

Can you provide me samples on how can I easily understand how to use json reader methods correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Be easy, just try GSON. There are many examples, articles about that

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit#overview
https://medium.freecodecamp.com/rxandroid-and-retrofit-2-0-66dc52725fff#.ymmfqdi9s
https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-retrofit-2/

According http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all response here is GSON models

```
public class County {
    @SerializedName("name") public String name;
    @SerializedName("alpha2_code") public String alpha2Code;
    @SerializedName("alpha3_code") public String alpha3Code;
}

public class RestResponse {
    @SerializedName("messages") public Messages messages;
    @SerializedName("result") public Countries counties;
}

public class CountriesResponse {
    @SerializedName("RestResponse") public RestResponse restResponse;
}   

public interface GroupktApi {
  @GET("/country/get/all")
  Call<CountriesResponse> getAllCountries()
}

public Gson provideGson() {
return new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Messages.class, MessagesDeserializer());
}

public class MessagesDeserializer extend JsonDeserializer<Messages> {

    @Override public Messages deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
      JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList();
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
          Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType();
          List<String> arrayMessages = context.deserialize<List<String>>(value, listType)
          messages.addAll(arrayMessages)
        } else {
          String message = json.asString()
          messages.add(message)
        }
        return new Messages(messages);
    }
}

public class Messages {
    public List<String> messages;

    public Messages (List<String> messages) {
       this.messages = messages;
    }
}
```

Countries in the same way

That's it

Comment: yes, but how do I handle fields where in they can return a List or a single object? That's why I'm using TypeAdapter to handle those scenarios. Do you have something in mind for this kind of scenario that is much efficient aside from the TypeAdapter?

Comment: If response could be in different format, yes, TypeAdapter and JsonDeserializer is your way

Comment: But on my TypeAdapter I'm confused on how does jsonReader methods works. Sometimes they seems to consume a json field and sometimes not. It's confusing.

Comment: I have updated the answer post. Is response format really can change? I provide some simple models for current response

Comment: @zbryan I got you, update post again with TypeAdapter

Comment: I see what you've did there but instead of using JsonDeserializer, can you use TypeAdapter? I have read somewhere that TypeAdapter is much efficient compare to the JsonDeserializer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn basic jSON parsing you should definitely read this [Android Json Parsing](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) ..... but in retrofit 2 you can use Model classes rather than json parsing.....I'm sharing my code below....
Model Class

```
public class WeatherResponse {

@SerializedName("cod")
@Expose
private String cod;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private Double message;
@SerializedName("cnt")
@Expose
private Double cnt;
@SerializedName("list")
@Expose
private List<cityList> list = null;
@SerializedName("city")
@Expose
private City city;

public String getCod() {
    return cod;
}

public void setCod(String cod) {
    this.cod = cod;
}

public Double getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(Double message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Double getCnt() {
    return cnt;
}

public void setCnt(Double cnt) {
    this.cnt = cnt;
```

API Client

```
public class ApiClient {
private static final int TIME_OUT = 30;
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder okBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        okBuilder.connectTimeout(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okBuilder.readTimeout(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okBuilder.writeTimeout(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL) .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okBuilder.build())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

API Interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
      @GET("data/2.5/forecast?id=524901")
      Call<WeatherResponse> getWeatherData(@Query("APPID") String apiKey);
}
```